# How to connect to mysql without using plain text?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make it so i can use username/password i've set in the properties/settings to connect to mysql as i dont want to store mysql details in plaintext here what i'm using but not sure how to go about reading the username/password from properties, Could anyone help? thanks

```
private void PassTextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        try
        {


            string MyConnection = "datasource=localhost;port=3309;username=user;password=pass123";
            MySqlConnection MyConn = new MySqlConnection(MyConnection);
            MySqlCommand MyCommand = new MySqlCommand("select * from applogin.users where UserId='" + this.UserTextBox.Text + "' and UserPassword='" + this.PassTextBox.Text + "' ;", MyConn);
            MySqlDataReader MyReader;

            recby = UserTextBox.Text;
            MyConn.Open();
            MyReader = MyCommand.ExecuteReader();
            int count = 0;
            while (MyReader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(MyReader[count]);
                count++;
            }
            if (count == 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Accepted, Welcome!");
                this.Hide();
                Form5 f5 = new Form5();
                f5.ShowDialog();
            }
            else if (count > 1)
            {

                MessageBox.Show("Duplicate Username and passwor.\nAccess denied.");
            }
            else

            {
                MessageBox.Show("Username and password is incorrect.\nPleas try again.");
            }
            MyConn.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Store the entire connection string outside of the code. In an asp.net core app it would be in appsettings.json for example but there are many other possibilities for different scenarios.

Comment: On a separate note, please, *please*, *PLEASE*, learn how to parameterize your queries.

Comment: As an aside, that's not what [plaintext](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plaintext) is. If these settings were put into a separate config file, they would still be plaintext (unless you encoded/encrypted the config file). Plaintext is just "readable" text, regardless of where it is stored (database, code file, text file, config file, ...). What you're asking about is how to do it without _hardcoded_ or _magic_ strings, i.e. no literal string values in code (at least as far as the connection string is concerned).

Answer (score 0):

```
class DBConnect
{
    private MySqlConnection connection;
    private string server;
    private string database;
    private string uid;
    private string password;

    //Constructor
    public DBConnect()
    {
        Initialize();
    }

    //Initialize values
    private void Initialize()
    {
        server = "localhost";
        database = "connectcsharptomysql";
        uid = "username";
        password = "password";
        string connectionString;
        connectionString = "SERVER=" + server + ";" + "DATABASE=" + 
    database + ";" + "UID=" + uid + ";" + "PASSWORD=" + password + ";";

        connection = new MySqlConnection(connectionString);
    }

    //open connection to database
    private bool OpenConnection()
    {
      bool flag=false;
      if (this.OpenConnection() == true)
      {
          //Create Mysql Command
          MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, connection);

          //ExecuteScalar will return one value
          Count = int.Parse(cmd.ExecuteScalar()+"");
          flag=true;
          
          //close Connection
          this.CloseConnection();

          return flag;
      }
      else
      {
          return flag;
      }
    }

}
```

Comment: Use the `MySqlConnectionStringBuilder` class instead of string concatenation to construct the connection string.

Comment: Caching a local connection is (also) a very very bad idea.  Connections should be created, used and disposed in the smallest possible scope.  the NET framework implements Connection pooling for you.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather recommend to read password from an environment variable instead of hardcoding it in the code.

Answer (score 0):

This is a broad topic.

Mainly, it is "how to store a 'secret' well?"

I'll give some hints.

First, in dotnet CORE, there is new stuff.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=windows

That is for local development, BUT AT LEAST forces you to think about where that secret is being stored.

Using .ini, .config, .txt files and keeping a secret in plain text IS NOT secure for production scenarios.

So then you have to start thinking about "how is my code deployed?"

If you are deploying to Azure, there is Azure Key Vault.

If you are deploying to a machine/VM, then you have to consider something more robust, like Hashicorp Vault.

But you're going to get a few "quick fix" answers.  You need to really consider where you keep this secret for your deployed code.

Answer (score 0):

If I read your question correctly, you don't care about the connection string userid/password but about the users login credentials.

This is based on your line:

```
MySqlCommand MyCommand = new MySqlCommand("select * from applogin.users where UserId='" + this.UserTextBox.Text + "' and UserPassword='" + this.PassTextBox.Text + "' ;", MyConn);
```

And it appears you are asking about how to encrypt the password so that someone can't monitor the communication. Of course, your connection string is already an issue, but back to what I believe is your question.

It's not clear if you are using the actual user name and password as entered or not.  If so, the easiest option is to use 1 way encryption - and only store the encrypted values.  Then your code would get the value of the textbox and encrypt it. Then execute a query with the encrypted value (preferably with those encrypted values as parameters, not inline text.)

The result would be a query that might look like:

```
select * from applogin.users where UserId='kajsdf09823rcfs98dsjssdf' and UserPassword='j;las9onq;p;9wf;kjadf' ;
```

and written correctly (assuming you have a method named encrypt that implements whatever encryption you choose):

```
userId = new SqlParameter("@userName", encrypt(this.UserTextBox.Text));
userpw = new SqlParameter("@userPw", encrypt(this.PassTextBox.Text));
cmd.Parameters.Add(userId);
cmd.Parameters.Add(userpw );

cmd.CommandText = "select * from applogin.users where UserId=@userName and UserPassword=@userPw ;";
```

There are other great suggestions as well, I encourage you to follow up on those as well.

Comment: Note: there are other ways - I just chose the syntax that best fits the apparent experience level for clarity.

Comment: the username & password from applogin.users isn't what i want to encrypt i want to encrypt the actual mysql details thats in plaintext? like is there anyway to put the mysql details without plain text

Comment: If you want to hide the connection string details, it becomes more tricky until MS adds the option.  Probably the easiest way would be to use a microservices approach - where you have a backend through which you make requests.  That can use whatever encrypted channel you wish.  Then that uses a connection string (which is only on the back end) to get the desired data and returns that to you.  Ping me if you want more details.